# running multiple queries through a single php mysqli_query function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a script that generates a SQL insert or update script depending on several factors. Below is the string value of the script it's generating:

```
INSERT INTO AAB_EVENT_SHIFTS ( EVENT_ID ,SHIFT ,START_TIME ,END_TIME 
    ,CREATE_USER ,CREATE_DATE ,MODIFY_USER ,MODIFY_DATE ) VALUES ( 6 ,1 
    ,STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2016 10:00 am', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p' ) 
    ,STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2016 11:00 am', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p' ) ,14 ,now() ,14 ,now() 
    ); INSERT INTO AAB_EVENT_SHIFTS ( EVENT_ID ,SHIFT ,START_TIME ,END_TIME ,CREATE_USER ,CREATE_DATE ,MODIFY_USER ,MODIFY_DATE ) VALUES ( 6 ,2 ,STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2016 11:00 am', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p' ) ,STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2016 12:00 pm', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p' ) ,14 ,now() ,14 ,now() ); 
INSERT INTO AAB_EVENT_SHIFTS ( EVENT_ID ,SHIFT ,START_TIME ,END_TIME ,CREATE_USER ,CREATE_DATE ,MODIFY_USER ,MODIFY_DATE ) VALUES ( 6 ,3 
,STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2016 12:00 pm', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p' ) 
,STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2016 1:00 pm', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p' ) ,14 ,now() ,14 ,now() );
```

If I run that in a sql editor connected to the database it runs perfectly fine and inserts all rows expected. However when calling that query thusly:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

echo mysqli_error($link);
```

returns this:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO AAB_EVENT_SHIFTS ( EVENT_ID ,SHIFT ,' at line 24`

I changed the way the query generates from creating a concatenated string of multiple queries to creating an array of queries and running them one at a time - this seems to have corrected the issue.

```
        for($i=1;$i<=$event->total_shifts($event_id);$i++) {
//        echo $event->shift_exists($event_id,$i).'-'.$i.'::<P>';
        if($event->shift_exists($event_id,$i)) {
            $query[$i] =
            'UPDATE AAB_EVENT_SHIFTS '
                    . 'SET START_TIME   = STR_TO_DATE(\''.$event->event_date($event_id).' '.$_POST['start_shift-'.$i].'\', '.'\'%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p\' )'
                    . ', END_TIME       = STR_TO_DATE(\''.$event->event_date($event_id).' '.$_POST['end_shift-'.$i].'\', '.'\'%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p\' )'
                    . ',MODIFY_USER     = '. get_session_user_id(session_id())
                    . ',MODIFY_DATE     = now()'
                    . ' WHERE EVENT_ID = '.$event_id.' AND SHIFT = '.$i.'; ';

        } else { $query[$i] =
                '
        INSERT INTO AAB_EVENT_SHIFTS
        (
        EVENT_ID
        ,SHIFT
        ,START_TIME
        ,END_TIME
        ,CREATE_USER
        ,CREATE_DATE
        ,MODIFY_USER
        ,MODIFY_DATE
        )
        VALUES
        (
        '.$event_id.'
        ,'.$i.'
        ,STR_TO_DATE(\''.$event->event_date($event_id).' '.$_POST['start_shift-'.$i].'\', '.'\'%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p\' )
        ,STR_TO_DATE(\''.$event->event_date($event_id).' '.$_POST['end_shift-'.$i].'\', '.'\'%m/%d/%Y %I:%i %p\' )            
        ,'. get_session_user_id(session_id()) .'
        ,now()
        ,'. get_session_user_id(session_id()) .'
        ,now()
        ); 
        ';

        }
        }

        $i = 1;
        while($query[$i]) {
        echo '<P>'.$query[$i];
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query[$i]);
            $i++;
        echo '<P>'.mysqli_error($link);
        }
```

Comment: Show how you create your `$query` variable!!

Comment: Add your $query or print the query & run the same in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run multiple queries through a single php mysqli_query function.
Just make your script generate an *array* of queries and then run them one by one in a loop.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it's working now. Thanks mate.

Comment: you can with mysqli_multi_query though?

Comment: @Jester using multi_query is not that easy

Answer (score 0):

you can either loop through the queries or you have to use the mysqli_multi_query function if you want to execute multiple with one function: [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)

Comment: As almost no one understands what mysqli_multi_query is and how to use it properly, it is strongly recommended not to use it for a silly case like this. An outcome may be surprising.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I guess so, must say haven't used it myself before but I thought it might be worth mentioning. In which case would you say it would be better to use it instead of executing them one by one, or just never?

Comment: When you need asynchronous query execution I'd say. In any other case it's better to do separate query calls.

Comment: I could use this elsewhere although it wasn't necessary for this purpose, thanks mate.